# Solution of a non homogeneous Laplace equation on the unit disk.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

The problem is the following:

> Let $B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the open unit disk. Solve 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> \Delta u = f \, &x \in B_1\\
> u = 1 \, &x \in \partial B_1
> \end{cases}$$

I'm kind of lost with this problem. First I tried to find the solution for the homogenous problem ($f \equiv 0$) using polar coordinates. The Laplacian in the case is written as
$$\Delta (r, \theta) = u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r + \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta}$$
So I tried to look for solutions of the form $u(r, \theta) = R(r) \Theta (\theta)$. Substituting in the equation $\Delta u = 0$ gives 
$$\frac{r^2 R''(r)+rR'(r)}{R(r)} = -\frac{\Theta(\theta)}{\Theta(\theta)} = \lambda$$
where $\lambda$ is a constant. The problem arises when trying the different values of $\lambda$ ($=, <$ or $>0$) since the boundary conditions are not "usual". Anyway here is my try for some cases.

If $\lambda = 0$, then $\Theta(\theta) = 0$ so $\Theta(\theta) = A_1\theta + A_2$. Now since in the boundary $\partial B_1$ the function is equal to $1$, then $\Theta(0) = A_2 = 1$ so $\Theta(2 \pi) =2 A_1 \pi + 1 = 1$, so $A_1 = 0$ and we get the solution $\Theta(\theta) = constant$. Also the radial part when $\lambda = 0$ reads $r^2R''(r)+r'R(r) = 0$ so the solution is 
$$R(r) = B_1 \log (r) + B_2$$
and since in the boundary this must be equal to $1$ I get $B_2 = 1$, so $R(r) = B_1 \log(r) + 1$. Plugging then $R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ in the equation $\Delta u(r, \theta) = 0$ the only possible value of $B_1$ is $0$, so the solution when $\lambda = 0$ is $u \equiv 1$.

When I do the computations for the cases $\lambda > 0$ and $\lambda <0$ the solutions for $\Theta$ are respectively 
$$\Theta(\theta) = C_1\cos(\mu \theta) + C_2 \sin (\mu \theta)$$
and
$$\Theta(\theta) = D_1e^{\mu\theta} + D_2e^{-\mu \theta}$$
where $\lambda = \mu^2$ in the first case and $\mu = -\lambda^2$ in the second.

> I'd appreciate son help with this cases or if there is another shorter path that doesn't involve this series of calculations. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: there is an obvious explicit solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: You can decompose your function $u$ as follows: $u = 1 + v$ and $v$ is a solution to $\Delta v = f$ in $B_1$ and $v = 0$ on $\partial B_1$. To compute $v$, I would suggest to follow the hint by Julián Aguirre

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Thanks for the hint. $u \equiv 1$ in the closed disk is a solution of course, but I don't know hot to continue from there.